# How to call the print() function in Google Colab

Tags: python, typeerror, google-colaboratory

I want to sum up a list named x and print the sum in Google Colab.

I tried running the print() function, and in return gave me an error.
`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Here's the code:

```py
a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x = sum(a)
print(a)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your tuple (not list, since you wrap with `(` and `)` instead of `[` and `]`) is called `a`, and the sum is called `x`.

Comment: You must have earlier done `print = some_number`. So it's not the function for printing, it contains that number, and you can't use it as a function any more.

Comment: Restart your session to get a fresh environment.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I refreshed and turns out Google Colab was being lazy. The print() function now works. Thanks y'all and happy Easter!